# GTM Google analytics dataLayer get wrong values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I defined a dataLayer to store some informations for pages, its looklike:

```
dataLayer =  {
pageType: "Page type",
mainCategory: "Main category of page", 
subCategory1 "Sub category level1",
     ...
}
```

Then I define custom dimensions:
custom_dimension1: mainCategory
custom_dimension2: subCategory1
..
With Scope is Session.

I use Google Tag Manager to debug and see variables record values exactly:
custom_dimenssion1 = "Main category of page",..

But, when I go to Google Analytics after day, i see with the Page url, i have multiple custom_dimension1 value:

```
PageA_URL:
mainCategory = Main category of page A (exact)
mainCategory = Main category of page B (wrong)
mainCategory = Main category of page C (wrong)
```

I dont know why? please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a custom dimension with session scope, the last value that it is given is the value that is recorded in GA. So on page A you may be giving it a value from the datalayer that you believe is correct for page A, but when you move to page B within the same session and again push a page category to the datalayer, that page B value is written to your custom dimension, and so forth until the session has ended. Whatever that last value was that gets pushed to your custom dimension is the final value for that particular session.

Comment: Thank you, i will change scope to Hit, I think it will be okey.